# Add Scope object listener

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have `$scope.number = 1`. I want to add a listener to update the path.

My try which doesn't work:

```
function LocationController($scope, $location) {
   $scope.$watch($scope.number, function(path) {
     $location.path('/'+$scope.number);
   });
}
```

Also, how is `$scope.number` called, object, subobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
function LocationController($scope, $location) {
   $scope.$watch('number', function(newNumber) {
     $location.path('/'+newNumber);
   });
}
```

Read [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) for the arguments to `$watch`